# reference to element inserted by document.write

Tags: javascript, embed, widget

I created an element in an outer javascript file:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
```

Now I need to append the lement to the body and still keep the reference to it (`element` variable).
But I need to append it right after the script tag - like `document.write()` would do it.

I can't use classes and id's for the script and the element itself - I'm not on my site and there could be more than one of those scripts.

How to solve such task?
CONTEXT: I'm want to build some widgets which could be used on others sites.

Comment: Why wouldn't you let your users decide where to place these widgets?

Comment: They decide where to place it by including the script tag. Like youtube does it with their iframe embeded codes. Unfortunately I can't use iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
if(typeof globalScriptCounter === "undefined")
  var globalScriptCounter = 1;
  else
  globalScriptCounter++;

var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var localCounter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
  if(scripts[i].src === "yourwidget.js") { // You should know the path since it is your widget
    localCounter++;

  if(globalScriptCounter === localCounter) {
    document.body.insertBefore(element, scripts[i]);
    break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I edited my code. Try it out!

Comment: You saved my live! After some small corrections I ended up with my code - see below.

Answer (score 0):

only creating element is not sufficient. use document.body.insertBefore, document.body.appendChild and other functions to add it to page elements list.

sample function

```
function addElement()
{
  // create a new div element
  // and give it some content
  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.

  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

Ref: [from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)

Comment: ...I can't use classes and id's for the script and the element itself - I'm not on my site and there could be more than one of those scripts....

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new element , you are assigning it to some variableName. So you can use the variable name itself for the reference to the variable.

Comment: I'm not polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this source:

Definitions for my framework (I think there are fair):

1. every widget script tag has a `myNamespace-widget-script` class
2. there is one global myNamespace object

The widget script:

```
!function() {
//-->BEGIN GET WIDGET INDIVIDUAL ID
var localWidgetCounter = 0;
if ( _.isUndefined(myNamespace) ) {
    myNamespace = {}
}
if ( _.isUndefined(myNamespace.widgetsCounter) ) {
  myNamespace.widgetsCounter = 0;
} else {
  localWidgetCounter = myNamespace.widgetsCounter += 1;
}
//-->END GET WIDGET INDIVIDUAL ID

$.domReady(function() { 
  var teaser = ...here i generate my html DOM elements...
      teaser.insertAfter($('.myNamespace-widget-script')[localWidgetCounter]);
});

}.call({});
```